# Moving from Geany to Sublime Text 3: how to run Python scripts in command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, sublime-text-3, python3, geany

I've been coding in Python 3.6 using the Geany editor for a while. When I run scripts in Geany, a Windows command prompt running Python will pop up and run the script. This I did using the build command `python -i "%f"` in Geany.

Now I've been trying out a different editor: Sublime Text 3. However, I find the in-built console doesn't work well for my needs, so as with Geany I'd like a Windows command prompt to pop up and run my code. How do I do this in Sublime Text 3?

Answer (score 0):

Try this thing out:
You might have created the python file in some directory just double click on it. There is one issue with this once the program ends the **CMD** window closes so try to give enough delay so that you could verify your output like this:

```
import time
```

and put the following as your last line

```
time.sleep(seconds) # put 120 like that i.e. 2 minutes it will wait before closing CMD
```

Or try this 
Open **CMD** and open the directory to your python file using `cd` to change directory, `e:` or `d:` to choose drive `cd..` to go back by one step to the parent directory 
if directed to your directory

```
python thefile.py
```

will open the python file with the name **thefile.py**
if the file is on desktop just type `python thefile.py` in the cmd.